# Why can't I link a static object with .rodata section to a shared library in 64-bit systems?

Tags: c, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries, relocation

I have created a static library (`libar.a`), which contains a function `foo`.

I have a shared object (compiled with `-fPIC` flag) file that calls `foo`.

If the object file containing `foo` has a `.rodata` section (e.g. a call to `printf` or a string literal), trying to compile the shared object with the static library fails with this error:

`relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/path/to/static/lib/libar.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I know I can solve it by using `-fPIC` to compile my static object, but I try to understand the reason I get this error.

P.S. While looking for it I found that this happens only on 64-bit platforms.

Thanks.

Comment: In short (I don't have time to research a proper answer, hence only a comment): it's not about the section (`.rodata`), but the type of the relocation (`R_X86_64_32`) that refers to it. If I remember correctly those simple relocations (`_32`) expect an absolute address for a symbol, but an absolute address for the symbol can not be calculated for a PIC object pretty much by definition. When linking things, either everything has to be PIC or nothing.

Comment: Just to explain a bit more. The code generated an instruction to load an absolute value into a register. Like if you have a `printf` with a normal format string, to load the address of the format string to the register. Without PIC the most efficient instruction to use may be "load number X in %Y". The compiler doesn't know the value of X at compile time, but generates a relocation that will compute X at link time. PIC code can not use those instructions since the address will not be know at link time, most likely the instruction used will be "load number X+%Z in %Y" ("%" denotes a register).